# jquery append item (xml infinite scrolling)

Tags: jquery, xml, append, jquery-isotope

I try to append elements form xml data file.

I success to do it onload. I append on load a certain number of element.

I want to use this append function to add next elements form the same xml data on click.

To do this, I add a condition if and variables. However nothing happen..

I think I have a problem with my if.

Here my script **EDIT WORKING SCRIPT**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $container = $('#container');
var $items = $('.element');
var $filter = $('#filter a');

function initIsotope() {
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: $items,    
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 4000,
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
            queue: false
        } 
    });
        $filter.on('click', function(){
    $container.isotope({
        filter: this.getAttribute('data-option-value')
     })
    });
    $(' #container > div ').each( function() { $(this).hoverdir(); } );
}


$.get('data.xml', function (d){
        first = $(d).find("element").last().attr("id");
    last = $(d).find("element").first().attr("id");
    init();     
});

$('#next').on("click", function() {
    init(); 
        $('#container').isotope({
itemSelector: '.element',  
        });
});


function init(){

$.get('data.xml', function (d){

            var nbOfelemet = 1;
            var nbToappend = last - nbOfelemet; 
            alert(last);
            alert(nbToappend);  

$(d).find('element').each(function (){  

    if ( $(this).attr("id") <= last ) {

            var $element = $(this);
            var id = $element.attr("id");
            var size = $element.attr("size");
            var category = $element.attr("category");
            var urlpage = $element.find('urlpage').text();
            var urlimage = $element.find('urlimage').text();
            var title = $element.find('title').text();      

var $newelement = $('<div class="element '+ size +' '+category +'" id="_'+id+'"></div>').html('<a class= "link" href="' + urlpage + '"><img  src="' + urlimage + '" class="thumbnail" />' + '<div>' + '<span>' + '<i class="icon-pencil"></i>' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + title + '</span><span class="more">more.</span></div></a></div>');

$container.isotope( 'insert', $newelement)

var next = id;      
last = id -1 ;  
if (  first == next ) {     
$("#next-container").fadeOut(500);
}       
return ( id != nbToappend);
   }
            });
            initIsotope();      
    });
}

})
```

Comment: I assume the IDs are increasing. So I would expect that when you get additional data, you want add it to the page if the ID is _greater_ than the last item loaded? (you're checking that it's less than or equal to)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I want to append elements from the highest id to the smallest. at first it load id=13 then id=12. On click I want to load id=11 then id=10. If I put less egal it takes on click id=13 id=12 and id= 11. Here why website example : http://freakyshape.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for jQuery Isotope:**

If you want to rebuild your isotope stack, do this:

```
$(selector).isotope( 'destroy' )
  .isotope( 'insert', elem-previous, null )
  .isotope( 'insert', elem-current, null )
  .isotope( 'insert', elem-next, function(){focusIsotopToCurrentId();} );

// focusIsotopToCurrentId() is an optional function if you want to
// create a callback function to focus your click on something
```

Now that everything is corrected, put the following where your insert currently is and pass in your variables to `elem-previous`, `elem-current` and `elem-next`.

Comment: Here a fiddle to see my entire script : http://fiddle.jshell.net/lolo34140/rny8b/ . and here my website : http://freakyshape.com/.  I think my problem come from the way I made the if condition and maybe my var. I have some difficulty to get the correct var inside or outside the function...

Comment: First pass through the source shows `last` is undefined. It looks like your `$.GET` function is overloading the first one.

Comment: Onload the element are correctly append and var are correctly get. On next click the var are correctly get but nothing happen. I think because of a wrong condition. I dont understand what you mean with the $.get ?

Comment: That normal if you check with JShint to have this kind of error. The script don't have wrong code. It's about the logical structure I think...

Comment: `'id' used out of scope.` most likely is whats causing your code not to work. I was getting `undefined` for `last` when I stepped through it.

Comment: But if you try here online : http://freakyshape.com/ . it works great to get id. I don't understand... How can I correct this So?

Comment: The code bombs because you are waiting for the first `$.get` to define what `last` is, that may not fire for a second. By then it is too late, because your `init()` function is already processing with an undefined variable. I would hoist your `init()` function to fire directly after `last = $(d).find("element").first().attr("id");`

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is still the same. I don't know what to write to append the next element on click. Maybe I can't write a if condition to do that...

Comment: `$(~selector~).append(~some HTML~);`

Comment: The append method works correctly. If I dont put the if; the next but works great but append always the same elements again and again. So my script works. Here a update fiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/lolo34140/rny8b/1/  . Look here http://freakyshape.com/ to see in action I put some alert. If you try to click twice on next button you will see alert undefined. That's normal. Because of the if.

Comment: I found one of my big mistake! The if! I don't put the } at the good line! If I put to line 66 instead of 62 (on fiddle), it append new element. But not completely in the right way. Onload id=13 and id=12. On click next id=12 and id=11 are append .... Normal because of a bad var comparison for the if I think...

Comment: You are actually only appending one element. You have two alerts. one for the current append and one for the last index. You probably want something along the lines of `$('#container').remove();$('#container').append(~lastIdElem).append(~currentIdElem).append(~nextIdElem);`

Comment: I solve my problem to append new element with before the end of the if : last = id -1 ; But I have a problem to call back isotope to element appended thanks to the next button...

Comment: this is from the documentation to append than filter new element      `$container.isotope( 'insert', $newelement)`. I don't know why it's working onload. But not after next click...

Comment: I solve the problem with this in the click function : `$('#container').isotope({
 itemSelector: '.element',  
});` But I don't really understand why I need to do this again here...

Comment: Maybe I am confused as to what the purpose of clicking `Next` is? Are you trying to simply add another image? Are you trying to cycle them to next one and keep the same amount on the screen? What exactly is it supposed to do?

Comment: The next button acted like a load more element (like infinite scroll). The same amout of element that is loaded onload is applied on the next button.

Comment: Its meant to replace `$container.isotope( 'insert', $newelement)` entirely.

Comment: Not good solution, I think in my case, because you can see this animation on screen...